# Question asked but it isn't showing up under "Questions"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions

I asked a question about 1 minute ago and it isn't showing up under "Questions" with no filters on. It does show in my profile as being asked. Is this a cache issue on a server?

Comment: And now it is there... took about 4 minutes. This seems to be slower then the other SE sites but maybe I'm just excited about the beta.

Comment: SE sites are a bit unstable today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Questions pages are heavily cached. It just takes a bit of time to show up. This effect is exaggerated when a site is first starting out.

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought it was going to be something like that.